# Consulta sobre Laravel y Eloquent

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Tengo un formulario con dos select y dos campos fecha, al pulsar el botón me hace una consulta con el valor des los dos select y "whereBetween" entre las fechas, ¿existe alguna forma de hacer que solo consulte según los select en los que se ha introducido un valor?

He editado la pregunta y añado el código del controlador.

```
    public function results(Request $request)
{
    $professionals = Professional::where('id', $request->input('professional_id'));
    $resources = Resource::where('id', $request->input('resource_id'));
    $fini = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($request->input('date_start')));
    $ffin = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($request->input('date_end')));
    $coordinations = Coordination::where('professional_id', $request->input('professional_id'))->where('resource_id', $request->input('resource_id'))->whereBetween('date', [$fini, $ffin])->get();

    return view('coordinations.results')->with(compact('coordinations', 'professionals', 'resources'));
}
```

Comment: Por favor edita la pregunta y compártenos el código que utilizas (controlador y vista) para poder darte una respuesta acorde.

Answer (score 2):

Lo otro que pudes hacer es, hacer una consulta en bruto con el método ->whereRaw() y si estás utilizando postgresql como motor de bd, utlizar la función COALESCE en la consulta(sino debes buscar una similar en el motor de bd que estes utlizando o crearla tú mismo). Algo como esto:

```
->whereRaw('professional_id = COALESCE(?,professional_id)', [$request->input('professional_id')])
```

y lo mismo con el otro where.

Lo que hace la funcion COALESCE() es retornarte la primera variable no nula. Por ejemplo si el ? lo reemplazamos por el numero a filtrar, hará el filtrado normalmente, pero si es nulo, retornará el segundo parámetro que es el mismo campo por ende no filtrará ya que esa condicion siempre es True.

edit: en MySQL sí se encuentra en la versión 5.6 al menos.

Answer (score 1):

Te recomiendo cambiar tu función y adaptarla a la siguiente, el ejemplo este te puede servir si deseas buscar por mas de 2 criterios como eran tus selects

```
public function results(Request $request)
{
    $professionals = Professional::where('id', $request->input('professional_id'));
    $resources = Resource::where('id', $request->input('resource_id'));
    $fini = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($request->input('date_start')));
    $ffin = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($request->input('date_end')));
    //Si ambos datos no son nulos, ejecuto la consulta tal y como la tenias
    if(isset($professionals, $resources)) {
        $coordinations = Coordination::where('professional_id', $request->input('professional_id'))->where('resource_id', $request->input('resource_id'))->whereBetween('date', [$fini, $ffin])->get();
    } else {
      //Sino asigno los valores a un arreglo apra verificar cual es null y no pasarlo a la consulta
      $campos = [$professionals, $resources];
      //Almaceno las propiedades por las cuales voy hacer los where, como profesional es el primer elemento del arreglo la propiedad es professional_id, y asi sucesivamente
      $propiedad = ['professional_id', 'resource_id'];
      //Recorro el primer arreglo y voy comprobando si tiene valor y está definido
      foreach($campos as $indice => $valor) {
        if(isset($camp)) {
          //Asigno a una variable el queryBuilder de mi consulta para ir anexando las consultas where
          $builder = (isset($builder)) ? $builder->where($propiedad[$indice], $request->input($propiedad[$indice])) : Coordination::where($propiedad[$indice], $request->input($propiedad[$indice]))->whereBetween('date', [$fini, $ffin]);
        }
      }
      //Obtengo el resultado general de la consulta
      $coordinations = $builder->get();
    }

    return view('coordinations.results')->with(compact('coordinations', 'professionals', 'resources'));
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta, he utilizado este metodo y funciona bien, lo único es que Laravel me da un error con "isset", pero lo he cambiado por !== y resuelto.

Answer (score 0):

Te propongo otra opción con el código un poco mas limpio. Espero que te sea de ayuda, no puedo testear el código porque no tengo tu proyecto, pero en teoría y basado en mi experiencia debería de funcionar.

```
public function results(Request $request)
{
    // Inicializo variables
    $professional_id = $request->input('professional_id'); // si no se pasan el valor es null
    $resource_id = $request->input('resource_id'); // si no se pasan el valor es null
    $professionals = null;
    $resources = null;

    $where_array = [];
    // Si se paso valor agrego al array para hacer el where y busco el profesional
    if($professional_id != null) {
        $where_array = array_merge($where_array, ['professional_id' => $professionals->id]);
        $professionals = Professional::find($professional_id);
    }
    // Si se paso valor agrego al array para hacer el where y busco el recurso
    if($resource_id != null) {
        $where_array = array_merge($where_array, ['resource_id' => $resources->id]);
        $resources = Resource::find($resource_id);
    }

    $fini = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($request->input('date_start')));
    $ffin = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($request->input('date_end')));

    $coordinations = Coordination::where($where_array) // solo va a hacer el where de las variables que no este nulas. En caso de no pasar ninguno de los dos devuele todos los registros
                                  ->whereBetween('date', [$fini, $ffin])->get();

    return view('coordinations.results')->with(compact('coordinations', 'professionals', 'resources'));
}
```